# Minimum norm problems - bound on solution

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, normed-spaces

Let $L$ be a linear subspace of a normed space $X$ and consider the minimum norm problem

\begin{equation}
\inf_{x \in L} ||x-x_0||
\end{equation}

where $x_0 \in X$ and $x \in L$. Suppose there exists a solution $x \in L$.

I want to show, that
\begin{equation}
||x|| \leq ||x_0||
\end{equation}

Using the triangle inequality, together with $0 \in L$ I get
\begin{equation}
||x|| \leq 2||x_0||
\end{equation}
but I feel like a tighter bound should be possible (consider the finite-dimensional 2-dimensional case, it is evident that $x$ must lie in a circle with radius less than ||x_0||)

**Edit:**

As was shown down below, the solution must not satisfy the bound. However I now realize this was not really my goal. What I wanted to do was to replace the problem

\begin{equation}
\inf_{x \in L} ||x-x_0||
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
\inf_{x \in L, ||x|| \leq ||x_0||} ||x-x_0||
\end{equation}

and show they are equal (ideally for both finite and infinite dimensional $L$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|(x,y)\|=|x|+|y|$, $L=\{(x,y):y=kx\}$, where $0<k<1$, and $x_0=(1,0)$. The minimum distance is achieved at $x=(1,k)$, with $\|x\|=1+k$ and distance $k$. The minimum distance such that $\|x\|\le1$ is achieved at $(\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{k}{k+1})$, with distance $\frac{2k}{k+1}$. (Draw a diagram.)

Your bound 2 is optimal.

Comment: I think this solves the question. Could you elaborate on the optimality of my bound? I assume you meant optimality in the sense that the bound becomes tight for $\lim {k \rightarrow 1, k < 1}$ (although for $k$ = 1 there is another optimal solution $x = (0,0)$)

Answer (score 2):

This is false. Counter-example: Conside $\mathbb R^{2}$ with $\|(x,y)\|=\max \{|x|,|y|\}$. Let $L$ be the $x-$ axis and $x_0=(1,1)$. The minimum distance is attained at many points, in particular at $(2,0)$. But $\|(2,0)\|>\|(1,1)\|$.

Comment: I am sorry, you are of course right but I have not worded the correct intent of my question. Please see my edit for the correction.